# Addition of a new category for invalidated flags

Tags: feature-request, flags

Before explaining about the feature request, please refer this link to understand the context: [The flags count isn't detailed perfectly](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19256/1103140)

---

[image: Flag]

The aforementioned flag is not categorised in the flags.

[image: Flag stats]

So why can't we create a new category for these kind of flags? The new category can be named as **miscellaneous**.

Comment: Here is a related post from Meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283463/missing-flag-in-flagging-history At the time the CM who answered indicated this been such a rare occurrence that a category for this was not needed. That is not to say things haven't changed over the last four years but it shows what people were thinking about this.

Comment: @MarkKirby that post gives a better answer to technastic_tc's previous meta question (linked in this one) than either of the references I found! Good find

Comment: @Zanna Google was hiding it under the "See more options from meta.stackexchange.com" link, I don't know why.